# Why 2^n and not n!: The Algorithm Design Manual: 1.2 Selecting the Right Job (page 10)

Tags: algorithm

land,

In the section (page 10), the author willingly used 2-power-n to try all possible combinations of sub-intervals to find the largest subset that contains the maximum number of non-overlapping jobs. I was thinking n! instead and hence couldn't get his logic to use rather 2-power-n. Kindly please help me right here.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is difficult to follow. Could you try writing it more clearly, please? Also, since many of us do not have the book, you should probably explain the scenario better.

Comment: Can you quote the original text. This question cannot be understood without having the book (which one by the way?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is 2^n because for each job it is either take it or not take it (0,1). In other words, there are two possibilities for each job. For *n* jobs it is 2^n.

n! Is total of permutations for n jobs, it is used when you have taken n jobs but you want to know all the possible sequences.

Comment: Ah, makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: My apology (to other readers) for overlooking describing in detail the nature of the problem and the name of the book. The context is taken from the book, "The Algorithm Design Manual - Steven S Skiena".